# Coredump error when using put_container API

Tags: griddb

I have written the sample code which use put_container API. However, error `coredump` is occurred.

Environment Details:

> - Sever and Client : both in 1 machine CentOS 7.
> - C Client : 4.3.0-1.linux (use rpm file in Github, at release page)
> - GridDB Server : 4.3.0-36424 CE (use rpm file in Github, at release page)
> - Python Client : use master branch in GitHub.

Sample Code below

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import griddb_python as griddb
import sys

factory = griddb.StoreFactory.get_instance()

argv = sys.argv

blob = bytearray([65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74])
update = True
propList0 = [["bnfb", griddb.GS_TYPE_TIMESTAMP], ["ccvb", griddb.GS_TYPE_INTEGER]]

try:
    #Get GridStore object
    gridstore = factory.get_store(host=argv[1], port=int(argv[2]), cluster_name=argv[3], username=argv[4], password=argv[5])

    #Create Collection
    gridstore.drop_container("test_error");
    conInfo = griddb.ContainerInfo("test_error",
                    [["name", griddb.Type.STRING],
                    ["status", griddb.Type.BOOL],
                    ["count", griddb.Type.LONG],
                    ["lob", griddb.Type.BLOB]],
                    griddb.ContainerType.COLLECTION, True)

    infolist = conInfo.column_info_list
    conInfo.column_info_list = propList0
    col = gridstore.put_container(conInfo)

    #Change auto commit mode to false
    col.set_auto_commit(False)

    col.commit()
    print("Successful!")

except griddb.GSException as e:
    for i in range(e.get_error_stack_size()):
        print("[", i, "]")
        print(e.get_error_code(i))
        print(e.get_location(i))
        print(e.get_message(i))
```

Error Details:

```
Error Code: 140003 | CC_UNSUPPORTED_OPERATION
Description: "Checking of client request failed."
Explanation of possible causes: "Operation may not be supported."
```